# jQuery UI theming

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to use in my module custom jQuery UI theme from the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I couldn't create *jQuery UI* tag.

Comment: it can't be separated by spaces or else it understands they are 2 different tags :)

Comment: This is the first question tagged with *jQuery Ui*. I don't have permission to create new tag :)

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [jquery_ui](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui) module, all you have to do is:

- Build a [custom download](http://jqueryui.com/download) for jQuery UI including your custom theme from ThemeRoller and copy it under the jquery_ui folder, following the instructions in the module's README.txt
- Alternatively, you could just build your custom theme, download it, and copy it to jQuery UI's theme directory

EDIT:

However, since Drupal 7 already ships with the latest jQuery UI, all you gotta do is download your custom jQuery UI theme and include it using one of the following methods:

- Copy the directory to your theme's folder and include the css file in your theme's .info
- Create a custom module, and implement [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) and use [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) to add your custom stylesheet:

  function mymodule_init() {
    $options = array(
      'group' => CSS_THEME,
      'every_page' => TRUE,
      'weight' => 9999
    );
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'), 'mymodule.css', $options);
  }

Comment: I haven't found drupal 7 version of *jquery_ui* and I don't think that coping my files into drupal core directory is the best way.

Comment: My bad, agreed, I've edited my original post to fix this :)

Comment: Doesn't *drupal_add_css* just add new css files but not replace them? I'm going to use jQuery UI only on a single page.

Comment: drupal_add_css replaces files with the same name, so if you name your css 'jquery.ui.theme.css' for example it will be used instead of the default version

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding the UI via `drupal_add_library()`, you can change the style using `hook_library_alter()`. For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_library_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_library_alter(&$libraries, $module) {
  unset($libraries['ui']['css']['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']);
  $libraries['ui']['css']['path/to/your/custom/theme/jquery.ui.theme.css'] = array();
}
```

Comment: I think this is the better method because likely it will be module specific. Also, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7, the stock Seven theme does this ([repository link](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/HEAD:/themes/seven/template.php#l103)) (abridged):

```
function seven_css_alter(&$css) {
  if (isset($css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css'])) {
    $css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'seven') . '/jquery.ui.theme.css';
  }
}
```

Modify accordingly—i.e. replace "seven" with the name of your theme, and point the path to your jQuery UI theme's CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the [jQuery UI theme](http://drupal.org/project/jqueryui_theme) module which manages multi THEMEROLLER generated UIs and attached these UIs to Drupal themes. Then set the jquery UI CSS classes for elements in Drupal with the modules such as [block class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class)/ node class/ webform css, etc.